# Creating multiple new rows using data from other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2017

Is there a way to add extra rows to a table, pulling the data from other rows? Specifically, I am needing to relate all teachers of a specific subject to all classes. Currently, the code looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    class
    teacher
    subject
FROM TeachingSets
```

and produces a table like this

| Class | Teacher | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | English |
| 2 | Bill | Maths |
| 3 | Carl | Maths |
| 4 | Dave | Science |
| 5 | Evan | Maths |

What I need to do is create a table that takes all maths teachers, and associates them with all maths classes, so that the new table looks like this:

| Class | Teacher | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | English |
| 2 | Bill | Maths |
| 2 | Carl | Maths |
| 2 | Evan | Maths |
| 3 | Bill | Maths |
| 3 | Carl | Maths |
| 3 | Evan | Maths |
| 4 | Dave | Science |
| 5 | Bill | Maths |
| 5 | Carl | Maths |
| 5 | Evan | Maths |

I have tried this:

```
SELECT 
    class
    CASE 
        WHEN subject = 'Maths' 
        THEN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT
                teacher
            FROM TeachingSets
            WHERE subject = 'Maths')
        ELSE teacher
    END AS teacher,
    subject
FROM TeachingSets
```

but it throws up an error as the subquery returns more than one value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly straightforward `join` logic:

## Query

```
declare @t table(Class int,Teacher varchar(10),Subject varchar(10));
insert into @t values
 (1,'Adam','English')
,(2,'Bill','Maths')
,(3,'Carl','Maths')
,(4,'Dave','Science')
,(5,'Evan','Maths')
;

select c.Class
      ,s.Teacher
      ,s.Subject
from @t as c
    join @t as s
        on c.Subject = s.Subject
order by c.Class
         ,s.Teacher;
```

## Result

| Class | Teacher | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | English |
| 2 | Bill | Maths |
| 2 | Carl | Maths |
| 2 | Evan | Maths |
| 3 | Bill | Maths |
| 3 | Carl | Maths |
| 3 | Evan | Maths |
| 4 | Dave | Science |
| 5 | Bill | Maths |
| 5 | Carl | Maths |
| 5 | Evan | Maths |

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code**

```
SELECT TBL.CLASS,ISNULL(X.TEACHER,TBL.TEACHER) TEACHER,TBL.SUBJECTS FROM 
TeachingSets as TBL LEFT JOIN (
SELECT * FROM TeachingSets WHERE SUBJECTS='MATHS'
)X ON  TBL.SUBJECTS=X.SUBJECTS
```

Comment: This script does not do what is asked for in the OP?  They want to assign all teachers of each subject to all classes of that subject.  You script is `Maths` specific.

Comment: in question it is mention that **What I need to do is create a table that takes all maths teachers, and associates them with all maths classes** .- @iamdave